# MySQL query - join different tables based on a precondition (value retrieved from a different table)

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have following tables :

```
1. club_members (id, type, name)
2. male_members (name, age, location)
3. female_members (name, age, location)
4. senior_members (name, age, location)
```

I need to select 1 of these 3 tables based on type retrieved from 1st table.
like for `type=male`, i will select from male_members and so on.

so i want to write a query similar to

```
select type, name , age , location from club_members , (2/3/4 table) where id=X ...
```

how to write such query.

may be using **`if/else`** or **`case`** statements

Comment: What have you tired so far?

Comment: How the tables are related to each others? By which columns? What are the foreign keys between the tables?

Comment: Also, how do you want the result looks like? Do you want only three columns `name`, `age`, `location` and put all the three types of members under them using `UNION` for example? or select each as a separate columns?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming **Name** as the link between tables.

```
select 
       C.type as Type,
       COALESCE(m.name, f.name, s.name) AS MemberName, 
       COALESCE(m.age, f.age, s.age) AS MemberAge, 
       COALESCE(m.location, f.location, s.location) AS Location
from club_members C
left join male_members M on C.name=M.name and C.type='Male'
left join female_members F on C.name=F.name and C.type='Female'
left join senior_members S on C.name=S.name and C.type='Senior'
where C.id='Your value'
```